# Do periodicalTask every 5 minutes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use PeriodicAgent and do something in backround, but the default interval for PeriodAgent is 30 mins, which is too long for my app. Is there any way (in wp7.0 or above) to change the interval?

Thank you in advance.

-Aaron

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. Even the 30 min interval is not guaranteed.

Comment: That's very disappointing, I hope we'll see some changes in the future editions~